# JPA why queries returining 2 objects doesn't work and the one returning one object works fine

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jpa

I'm using EclipseLink JPA ver 2.5.1.

I have 3 queries which only differ by the columns returned.

The following queries are executing correctly:

1)

```
SELECT p.id, i.id 
FROM PtpFSP_R7DBImpl p, IntraNeConnectionDBImpl i 
WHERE i.neID=:neId AND i.neID=p.neID AND ((i.entityAEndpointAidString = p.aidString)  
  OR  (i.entityBEndpointAidString = p.aidString))
```

2)

```
SELECT p 
FROM PtpFSP_R7DBImpl p, IntraNeConnectionDBImpl i 
WHERE i.neID=:neId AND i.neID=p.neID AND ((i.entityAEndpointAidString = p.aidString)  
  OR  (i.entityBEndpointAidString = p.aidString))
```

Why the following one returns exception?:

3)

```
SELECT p, i 
FROM PtpFSP_R7DBImpl p, IntraNeConnectionDBImpl i 
WHERE i.neID=:neId AND i.neID=p.neID AND ((i.entityAEndpointAidString = p.aidString) 
 OR  (i.entityBEndpointAidString = p.aidString))
```

And the exception (which seems to be nonsense) is as follows:

> Exception [EclipseLink-6015] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException Exception
>   Description: **Invalid query key [entityAEndpointAidString] in
>   expression.**

I know such a query is not optimal but why doesn't it work anyway?

Comment: hey are you doing query.getResultList() for the last query? Try that.

Comment: Sure, I'm executing each of these by getResultList().

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't know how to map a (p, i) into an Object  but it should be able to manage the projection, though.
Your mapping must be incorrect. Check the relationships.